# How to stop warning message on only one function

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting the following error:

```
2016-05-24T15:56:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Declaration of EbayEnterprise_MultipleCoupons_Model_Validator::_canProcessRule(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule $rule, Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) should be compatible with Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::_canProcessRule($rule, $address)  in /home/public_html/app/code/community/EbayEnterprise/MultipleCoupons/Model/Validator.php on line 15
```

I want to stop this error from showing without stopping any other errors.

Line 15 has this:

```
class EbayEnterprise_MultipleCoupons_Model_Validator extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator
{
```

I've tried...

```
class EbayEnterprise_MultipleCoupons_Model_Validator extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator
{
    ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
```

this doesn't work.

I tried adding the @ symbol at various places still I get errors, most they stop my page from showing.

Is there a way to stop just this one error?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, but you could do what the message tells you?

Comment: I don't think this error can be fixed. Not by me anyway! :)

Comment: Fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: That said, you certainly _do_ want to suppress error visualization on a production system, though. But you cannot do that _inside_ a class. Move the `ini_set()` call out of the class definition into global scope. Better even disable error visualization in the php configuration (`php.ini`).

Comment: I tried putting **ini_set( "display_errors", 0);** above the class but it causes the page to break. Surely there is a way to say **if error don't report**  : )

Comment: Actually it didn't cause the page to break. It just didn't work. I still had the code below and didn't notice.